# Ansible - dealing with unexpected STDOUT in custom module

Tags: ansible, stdout, ansible-module

I wrote a custom module that wraps a Python library. I define `result` dict as follows:

```
result = dict(
    changed=False,
    original_message='Running DBSCONTROL',
    message=''
)
```

Later in code I wrap the call to the library into `try/except` as such:

```
try:
    dbsc = DbsControl(
        module.params.get('user'),
        module.params.get('host'),
        module.params.get('script')
    )
    dbsc.runme()
    result['message'] = 'DBSCONTROL_SUCCESSFULL'
    module.exit_json(**result)
except Exception as ex:
    result['message'] = str(ex)
    module.fail_json(msg='Failed DBSCONTROL execution', **result)
```

I do not have a single `print` statement anywhere in the module and my lib outputs log into a file.

Finally I call this Ansible role

```
- name: Run dbscontrol utility
  dbscontrol:
    user: "{{ hostvars[groups['dbs_server'][0]]['ansible_user'] }}"
    host: "{{ groups['dbs_server'][0] }}"
    script: "dbscontrol_config.yml"
  register: result
- debug:
    msg: "{{ result }}"
```

From the last logger message in my lib I can clearly see that the run completed successfully however my module ends up failing with massive output from the logger messages that starts with

```
MSG:

MODULE FAILURE
See stdout/stderr for the exact error
```

Oddly enough I see `result` embedded into MODULE_STDOUT section of the output. In fact it's the last section before MODULE_STDERR starts

Both MODULE_STDOUT and MODULE_STDERR consist of identical logging messages from the lib with the only difference of `result` related lines:

```
2020-01-23 13:40:52,070 - ttautils.dbscontrol - INFO - DBS control run is complete, exiting

{"changed": false, "original_message": "Running DBSCONTROL", "message": "DBSCONTROL_SUCCESSFULL", 
    "invocation": {"module_args": {"user": "root", "host": "fiesta1.td.teradata.com", "script": 
    "dbscontrol_config.yml", "dbc_user": "dbc", "dbc_pwd": "dbc", "logfile": "dbscntl_2020-01-23-13-38-15.log",  
    "loglevel": "DEBUG", "validate": "False", "config": "user_config/common", "locale": "TPG_6700C", 
    "timeout": "7200", "disable_local_overrides": false, "params": "user_config/user.yml"}}, 
    "warnings": ["The value False (type bool) in a string field was converted to 'False' (type string). 
        If this does not look like what you expect, quote the entire value to ensure it does not change."]}
```

The problem is that module always ends up as "failed" and the playbook terminates even I know that my code ran successfully.

**2 days later**

Ok, I know the problem now. It's due to the library I'm wrapping writing output to STDOUT/STDERR since it's using subprocess internally. When Ansible tries to parse the STDOUT it fails [in this method](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/9b7198d25ecf084b6a465ba445efd426022265c3/lib/ansible/plugins/action/__init__.py#L984) because of all the extra non-JSON output in the STDOUT.
How to deal with this situation? How can I possibly guarantee that my custom module has a pristine STDOUT with only JSON-formatted output? I was trying to do `sys.stdout.flush()` to no avail.

This practically renders writing a custom module useless. Please Ansible gurus, any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer to this problem is simple: when you call `exit_json` or `fail_json` you can't have `sys.stdout` with any sort of output. The reason is also simple: after your code is ran the result is processed by [this Ansible code](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/9b7198d25ecf084b6a465ba445efd426022265c3/lib/ansible/plugins/action/__init__.py#L984). Which parses `res.get('stdout', u'')` and if there are any parsing errors then you end up with that massive STDOUT dump I mentioned in my question.

The solution is not that simple. I tried various hacks to empty STDOUT before calling Module exit methods but it didn't really worked. So since I have a full control over what I'm calling I simply changed my logging to temp-files based in the library I call and did few other things to ensure that I'm not using `sys.stdout` in any way. Which is really silly and I hope that someone can show me a better way